# how to show two views back to back to the user, using django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like to implement the following using django web framework:

1. dynamic webpage displayed to user with form control
2. when user press submit button, show her another webpage asking to wait
3. In the background, process the collected form data by sending it to a backend server
4. After response/timeout from backend server, show a thank you or Error webpage to the user

I know that I can define a view for step2.
But how do I automatically show a new view "unsolicited" for step4?

I am using Django 1.9 and python 3.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have async user form data worker which starts i background, so you can start handler and return HTTPResponse.
Consider next flow to perform desired steps:

1. Send post to `view1` from page1.
2. Create flag variable in session, start user form data handler by `view1` with unique identifier and return page2.
3. Create `js function` which would periodically ask `view2` whether redirect should be performed.
4. `view2` check whether session flag is changed if it is return `{'redirect': True, 'redirect_url': url}`.
5. Background handler of form should update session flag to true so `view2` would catch that moment and return right answer to js.
6. `JS Function` would redirect to right url or sleep for a little before next ask to `view2`.

Checkout 
[How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions) to get familiar with django sessions.

`JS Function to check for redirect`:

```
function checkRedirectionFlow(){
  # assume you have jQuery
  $.get('route/view2').done(function(response){
    response['redirect'] && location.replace(response['redirect']);
  })
}
setInterval(checkRedirectionFlow, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. i just needed a simple solution. Looks like your suggestion will fit. Webapp dev is not my primary activity, so will try when time permits and confirm

Comment: Cool, glad to assist you. If you need simple solution what you can do is that simply redirect (by next code: `setTimeout(function(){location.replace(response['redirect'])}, 10000)`) from page2  to page3 (without verifying whether form processing finished , (you assume that it processed in `10000` milliseconds).
But note that that's not good practice  ...

Answer (score 0):

When user press submit button, your server receives collected data and returns another webpage (waiting page), the HTTP request cycle is over. You cannot return response for a single request 2 times.

You should use javascript for this purpose. When user press submit button, collect and post data using javascript, show waiting message (text or html) using javascript, when server returns response (final response from your step 4) display that using javascript.

On a side note, you have not mentioned how long your background task will take. If it is a long running task then you should consider using an distributed asynchronous task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: The background task should take only couple of seconds